# What is small kanji part that is usually placed on the left of a japanese calligraphy (shodō) work?

Tags: kanji, calligraphy

There are generally small kanji on a japanese calligraphy (shodo) work. Sometimes they are written above an inkan or inkan set. What are these kanji for? What types of information is written like this conventionally? Is this a necessary part of a shodo work? I think they contain some meta information about the work but I'm not sure.

Example image is below. [image: small meta kanji]

Comment: More often than not it's the calligrapher's name.

Comment: Could be a name, could also contain a location/time where/when it was drawn/written. This one is just a name (龍戾).

Answer (score 1):

that's a signature. (usually the name of the calligrapher)